# How to properly configure SSL certificates on a Synology NAS?

Tags: ssl, synology

While Synology DSM is a wonderful product, that was designed to be easy to be used, it seems that there a  few areas where it lacks documentation (even from online sources).

In fact most of the problems I am encountering would apply for any NAS devices you may want to configure for home. The only specific issue is the inability to configure ports 80/443 for the admin interface (because they are used by the local webserver)

Here are few requirements or facts:

- A certified SSL certificate is a must (no self-signed would do it)
- SSL certificate must be mobile friendly, otherwise no mobile apps, nor ChromeCast support
- You need to redirect HTTP to HTTPS
- You need to make it work on 80 and 443, no other custom ports (how!?)
- Be able to access the NAS from both intranet and internet using the same FQDN, even if the NAS is behind a problematic NAT-ed router (like the BT ADSL ones)

Regarding issuers, I found Comodo Essential SSL Certificate at 10$/yr with no SAN support so it will not work with both: mynas.synology.me and mynas.example.com at the same time.

Comment: You are asking several questions, which are not closely related to each other. You might get quicker answers if you create seperate questions for them. If the 'custom port 80/443' is the only actual question you have, change your post to reflect this.

Comment: @mtak the nature of this problem makes it harder to split. Anyway, I had some progress on this and as soon I will have a working solution, I will post it. It seems to be harder than it appears.